# Export project as jar file using manifest

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I just wrote Java console project , which i shoud pack as jar file. I googled it alot and found different solutions like (Eclipse) Project -> New Configuration -> e.t.c Then export as jar file using speciefied config. That's nice, but it's not what i need. After making repeatedly - it won't work. I tried to do same as mentioned here: [click](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mE3rbtKm-pk)

Second Solution: create jar using manifest. Well it's much better, because i can specifiy entry point of main.class. But it's won't work due to can;t find out where's annother packages.

Upd: Launcher.class looks like this

```
package backpack.dao;

public class Launcher{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Backpack.start();
}
}
```

My project structure:

```
src/backpack/dao/Item.java
                /Backpack.java
                /Chromo.java
src/backpack/main/launcher/Launcher.java
```

The Question is: What should i write in manifest instead of this:

`Main-Class src/backpack/main/launcher/Launcher` to make executable jar 
successfully?

P.S Launcher class uses instances from Backpack.java
Please don't downgrade. I'm rookie

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the package of the Launcher.java? Have you included package name to the classname in manifest.txt? 
Remember, when Launcher.java is in package "backpack.main.launcher" your classname in manifest.txt will be:

```
Main-Class src/backpack.main.launcher.Launcher
```

instead of:

```
Main-Class src/backpack/main/launcher/Launcher
```

Also, remember about this:

> The text file must end with a new line or carriage return.

To check what exactly is wrong with your jar file run it in the command line using:

```
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

and paste here output with error message.

For more help you can check this example from Oracle: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

***Edit:***

I recreated your project structure and I have found the solution (at least I think I have :) )

1. Compile your code and go to the parent directory with compiled code (with *.class files, this should be "out" directory or something like this - depending from your IDE). For example: when your project is in `some/path/src/backpack/main/launcher` go to `src` directory.
2. Run command: 
   `jar cvfe MyJar.jar backpack.main.launcher.Launcher -C . .`
   (Yes, two dots at the end)

This should create jar with name `MyJar.jar` and manifest file (-e flag) with main class `backpack.main.launcher.Launcher`. -C flag include all *.class files recursively from directory `.` (current one), so both from `dao` and `launcher` package.

3. Test jar: `java -jar MyJar.jar`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this isn't a good solution. because at launcher.class i invoke method of annother class. This class locates at annother location. so after creating jar via cli ( i receive error 2: 'can't see backpack.dao package').

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about structure of your project:

1. What is package of Item.java, Backpack.java and Chromo.java? 
2. According to structure of your project how it is possible that Launcher.java is in package `backpack.dao`? It should be in `backpack.main.launcher` package. Does your project compile?
3. Why do you need to insert Launcher.java in separate directory?

Comment: Hello. Yes, I double checked project. So I'm glad to answer to your questions: 1. All three classes belong to `backpack.dao` package.
2. Simply, I invoke static method run from Backpack.class.  No, Launcher already is on `backpack.main.launcher` package 3. Yes. I know it's lil' bit weird why I run program like this, but it prevents me from messing in the code ;)

P.S project compiles and run succesfully. The Only thing i need is to pack it as WAR file.